# Find source of mistake: git push rejected: error: failed to push some refs

Tags: git, git-push

In one of the teams, when working with git, again and again we run into "git push rejected: error: failed to push some refs"

> To git@git.far-mteria.org:ledy/thakres.git  ! [rejected]
>   b_stable -> b_stable (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some
>   refs to 'git@git.far-mteria.org:ledy/thakres.git' To prevent you from
>   losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected Merge the
>   remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the 'Note
>   about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

Of course, we can continue with "-f" as quick'n'dirty - not really a - solution.

However, we'd like to know where this comes from or what's the reason for this rejection.

Can't git give verbose details about the reason why it's rejecting, maybe the file which is causing the conflict?

We have a suspect on .gitignore which was causing similar issues on another project.

Comment: Ain't you're getting real error message? e.g.:  `! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.somewhere.git'`

Comment: editing and add the missing part of message. however, git does not tell me about the exact source or file which is causing troubles.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't push individual files one at a time, it pushes complete commit trees, as in, "here is how the entire project looked at one commit, and then it looked like that at another, and now finally it looks like this".

Drawn as a graph of commits, this is, e.g., the very linear:

```
...--D--E--F--G    <-- master
```

What's being "rejected" is that the "finally" you're supplying is not "forward progress" from the "finally" the remote had before, i.e., you're missing some "forward progress" that *someone else* put in.  You had:

```
...--D             <-- master
```

and then you added commits `E`, `F`, and `G`.  But while you were doing that, someone else picked up the series of commits ending in `D` and added his or her own commit `H`:

```
...--D--H          <-- master
```

You're proposing to throw away `H` and make the commit sequence look like *your* sequence: `D` is followed by `E`-through-`G` and that's the end of everything.

Git tells you the *branch name* that has the progress you're proposing to throw away, in this case, `master`.  It's up to you to `git fetch` the progress and then retain it, perhaps by `git merge` creating a merge commit `M`:

```
       H------
      /       \
...--D         M   <-- master
      \       /
       E--F--G
```

or perhaps by "rebasing" your series of commits on top of `H`:

```
...--D--H-E'-F'-G' <-- master
```

(where `E'`, `F'`, and `G'` are versions of "what changed in `E`, `F`, and `G`" with just enough changed to make them apply on top of `H` instead—quite often that's just commit parentage, occasionally there's a bit more work involved).

Comment: first of all, thanks for the detailled explanation. anyways, how to analyze the exact source of mistake at this point? Can't git tell me, which part of the tree is missing or give a hint where this can be found exactly? In the history, I see no other one than me who added a commit to the master. they added their changes into several branches different from master. however, if they are updating b_stable and I try commit and push to master, this conflicts with notice about b_stable <- that i did not care about...

Comment: As above, you have to use `git fetch` to pick up "their" commits.  You should set up a "remote" that names the URL and provides a name-space to track "their commits".  If your repo was cloned from `git@git.far-mteria.org:ledy/thakres.git` originally it already has a remote named `origin` that points there.  Then `git fetch origin` will bring over all necessary commits and update `origin/master` to denote them.  Use `git log origin/master` or `gitk --all` to view "their" commits and decide what to do.  If it's just `git merge`, you can use `git pull`; see other SO posts.

Comment: Also (ran out of space): `git push` can take a branch name; `git push origin master` limits the push to pushing just the `master` branch to remote `origin`.  (Eventually you may want to decide what to do about `b_stable` too but that can be later.)  This is probably what you want for the moment.

Comment: please correct me if i am wrong; but this `git fetch` will overwrite my own changes, doesn't it?

Comment: No, the nice thing about `git fetch` is that (with normal setups) the only thing it does is add new commits under the `refs/remotes` name-space.  This lets you see what other people did, but does not touch any of your own branches, which are under the `refs/heads/` name-space.  (The "remote branch" `origin/master` is really `refs/remotes/origin/master`, in that other name-space.)

Comment: `git fetch` and `git fetch origin` runs without any action or modification. empty output, nothing to do... finally, it's still rejecting when pushing again. Also, `git status` is telling me that there is nothing different, not in master, not in b_stable. Though, push is rejected. Although I could easily skip this with `-f`, I'd really be glad to fix instead of force and find out why this is happening again and again.

Comment: I suspect you have a `b_stable` that is *not* set to track `origin/b_stable`, and/or some interesting `push` configuration items.  What does `git config --get-regexp '^branch\..*'` show, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

Do a git pull, then try to push, that's what the message is saying.

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. As described, with `-f` it can be forced and overwritten, but that's not a fix or detail on the source of mistake that I am looking for.

Comment: Yes but read @torek's answer that explains about branches. May need to checkout the appropriate ones first.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a hard to find issue that I had several times, when disk is not sync or overload, high iowait.

Is `git show-branch --list --all` worrying about ambigious branch names: "warning: refname xyz is ambiguous"?

If so, try

> $ rm -rf .git/refs/heads/origin/xyz
>
> $ git branch --set-upstream lkgr origin/xyz